# Python3 Selenium - Failed to extract the text value from an element in a HTML page (web scraping)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML in a web page where I need to retrieve number of jobs in a table:

```
<span class="k-pager-info k-label">1 - 10 of 16 items</span>
```

I can find the element succesfully in various ways, but when I try to retrieve the number of rows, the 16 in "1 - 10 of 16 items",   it returns NULL.

I find the element as below which gives the element session and GUID:

```
job_items = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.k-pager-info.k-label')
print('Jobs: ', job_items)

Output:  Jobs:  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f528f37ec897b8c5006b3b5040a99c12", element="758533ea-800f-4895-ba66-e8247e882edb")>
```

Getting the same element using Xpath and now requesting the text value:

```
job_items = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span[2]').text
print('Jobs1: ', job_items)

Output:    Jobs1:  No items to display
```

I tried XXX.get_attribute("innerHTML") as well, also returns empty list / NULL

What am I missing please?

Comment: can you confirm the url, maybe there is a better way of getting that info?

Comment: It is unfortunately and internal autheticated website.   Thanks for the response

Answer (score 2):

In the first part you are missing `.text`
it should be

```py
job_items = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.k-pager-info.k-label').text
print('Jobs: ', job_items)
```

The command `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.k-pager-info.k-label')` returns a web element object. To extract its text `.text` should be applied on it.

In the second part you already applying the `.text` on the returned web element object so nothing is assigned to `job_items` .
To make it work and to be similar you can do the following:

```py
job_items = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.k-pager-info.k-label')
print('Jobs: ', job_items.text)

job_items = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span[2]')
print('Jobs1: ', job_items.text)
```

Comment: That was also my first goto - you will see in the second exmaple above that the .text was added.     However the output is:  " No items to display".    

I also tried:

job_items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                    '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span[2]')  

for job in job_items:
 print('Jobs2: ', job.text)

Comment: I saw that, please see the updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately  all the options returns " No items to display"   

`print('Jobs4: ',driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.k-pager-info.k-label").get_attribute("innertext")) 
'`
This returns " None"

Comment: You probably need to add a wait to ensure that the element is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. In your first attempt you printed the element itself, that's why you see the output as:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f528f37ec897b8c5006b3b5040a99c12", element="758533ea-800f-4895-ba66-e8247e882edb")>
```

where as in your usecase you want the *`innerText`*. So you have to use the *text* attribute or *`get_attribute()`* method.

---

### Solution

To print the text ***1 - 10 of 16 items*** you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.k-pager-info.k-label").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='k-pager-info k-label' and text()]").text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```

---

To extract the text **1 - 10 of 16 items**_ ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.k-pager-info.k-label"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='k-pager-info k-label' and text()]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Comment: I have the .text in the second example above - the output is then as below:

 job_items = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span[2]').text

         print('Jobs1: ', job_items)

Output:    Jobs1:  No items to display

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thank you for the comments - I do have earlier in the code the WebDriverWait(driver, 30)  to esnure the page is fully loaded.   Selenium seens so skip over this element, when I list all the elements in the class it list 4, but is skips over the text I need.

Comment: Checkout the updated xpath and let me know the results.

Comment: The last XPATH wildcards still misses the 1 - 10 of 16 items which is a few lines below the "no items to display" which has the same class_name.  It seems the scaning does not run through the full page.

Comment: I found alternative way to check the list size - thanks for all the assistance